# How to set FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE to change the language

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I create several Text Messages in different languages. But how can I set the variable "FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE", to show the Textmessages in another speech.

Answer (score 2):

to set a preference, and FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE is one use
apex_util.set_preference procedure.
Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_util.htm#CHDJDCAC

Example (set Language Preference to en-us for current user):

```
apex_util.set_preference( p_preference => 'FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE'
                        , p_value      => 'en-us'
                        );
```

hth,
Moritz

Comment: This will maintain to other pages as well ?